# `Record` type behaves differently than mapped type

Tags: typescript

Consider following example:

```
function foo<T extends string>(t: T): Record<T, string> {
  let r1: Record<string, string> = { bar: "baz" }
  r1.foo = "Some other property"

  const r2: { [P in T]: string } = r1 // "manual" mapped type
  // error (expected); Record<string, string> not assignable to {[P in T]: string}

  const r3: Record<T, string> = r1 // built-in type; internally a mapped type, too
  // works? Isn't the declaration the same as above?

  return r1; // this shouldn't be compatible with declared return type 
};

const t = foo("a")
```

- `r1` is *not* assignable to `r2` and triggers an error as expected.
- `r1` *is* assignable to `r3`, which I would consider wrong. `Record<string, string>` is not the same as `Record<T, string>`.

In addition I thought, that `Record<T, string>` is *equivalent* to `{ [P in T]: string }`. Hence following questions:

1. Why is `Record<T, string>` different from `{ [P in T]: string }` in terms of assignability?
2. Why can I assign `r1` to `r3` (is this a bug)?

Comment: I also don't fully understand it yet, but if I change it to `T extends string | number | symbol` (which is what the first parameter of `Record` can take), I get errors where you expect them.

Comment: thanks, good hint! This constraint will trigger the desired error. But I am still curious, what is the cause for the behavior in question - any issue or documentation links are greatly appreciated.